# Recognizing colors/patterns in webpage

Tags: java, image-recognition, chess, awtrobot

I want to try to create a learning chess application as a school project. My first plan was to simply pit this AI against itself, but to really show if it has been succesful it needs to be able to show how well it progresses. In order to do this, i want it to play rated games on sites such as chess.com. However, they do not (yet) have a public API, i believe.

Therefore, i wanted to make a program in java that recognizes colors and images. It keeps an internal 2-dimensional array of all the positions, and recognizes the pieces on the board. I think i have found a way to do this in a window using something like the [Java Robot Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

What i would like it to do, however, is to open this webpage in an internal window and keep doing this in the background. Is there a way to recognize colors within the own window, without needing to be in the foreground?

Edit: I'm planning on using [this browser component i just found](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html). I noticed that it is possible to create a full-page snapshot of the page and save it as a BufferedImage(?). Would this make it easier to do this?

Edit 2: I just read that 'Outside assistance from other people, computers/chess engines, or endgame tablebases is entirely prohibited'. I suppose letting a computer do all the playing does certainly include in that. So i might try using another site, so answers that are specific for chess.com won't cut it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know it it helps but may be you can have a look at the Sikuli project.
http://sikuli.org/

Sikuli is a program (and an API) to handle the interactions with the User Interface. For instance, you can write a script to click on an image or a button in certain conditions.

Especially interesting for you, there is a Java integration: http://sikuli.org/docx/faq/030-java-dev.html

Here is an extract of the website to give you an idea of the code you can write.

**EDIT**: in this code it is important to notice that you are defining new Patterns with the images. Sikuli will be able to find matching patterns.

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;

public class TestSikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Screen s = new Screen();
            try{
                    s.click("imgs/spotlight.png", 0);
                    s.wait("imgs/spotlight-input.png");
                    s.type(null, "hello world\n", 0);
            }
            catch(FindFailed e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should consider playing on a chess server where an API is avaible and chess engines are allowed. There is [The Internet Chess Club (ICC)](http://www.chessclub.com/) where you must pay to have a human account and then you can get a free computer account for your engine. There is also the [Free Internet Chess Server (FICS)](http://www.freechess.org/) where you and your engine can get free accounts.

The ICC is usually prefered because the level of players is higher there with lots of international masters and chess masters playing there.

The best way to Interface with theses sites is to implement the [xboard protocol](http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/engine-intf.html). This will allow your engines to play through the Winboard or XBoard interface (among others) and theses interface can be used to connect on FICS or ICC and automatically play there.

I hope this help, even if it does not directly answer the question.

Comment: This is some awesome information! I'd seen that website before but always skipped it somehow. I'll try to implement this, thanks a bunch! These are the occasions i wish i could accept 2 answers... Both solve my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hmm, when i register i have to say i wont get any help from a.o. computers. What about a fully computer controlled account? Wouldnt that kinda violate that rule?

Comment: Once you have registred your human account you can request a computer account, such request are done by email if I recall correctly. Here are the informations for FICS : http://www.freechess.org/Help/HelpFiles/computers.html. It's fine if you don't accept my answer since I was not really answering the question you asked.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot again! I will accept the other, too bad i can't give you more than one upvote though ;)

Comment: -1. The answer is wrong and should be downvoted. Playing on ICC doesn't need XBoard protocol. Please don't write incorrect answers and mislead people.

Comment: @Kinderchocolate: I'm sorry, but I don't think my answer is wrong. I stated the best way to interface with ICC was to implement the xboard protocol, then use XBoard or WinBoard. There certainly is other ways, like speaking directly to ICC or implementing the UCI protocol, but what I said was still right and I can't see how it's misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your input is but you have two options:

1. You can work an a PNG image. Load the image into a `BufferedImage` ([docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)) object and examine it there. You can use a screen shot tool to create those.
2. It seems chess.com uses HTML with JavaScript. You can download the HTML using [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and examine it to see where the pieces are. This has the additional benefit that you don't have to guess which piece goes where since the HTML contains the source information.

Comment: How would you analyze a BufferedImage? I have some plans of applying color filters so you only see one player at a time, but is there a easy way to recognize the images of the pieces?

Comment: No; but you said you already had the code to recognize pieces in images. If not, you need to look into OCR (optical character recognition). In your case, it might be sufficient to count the number of black pixels in a field. That number should be different for all 15 chess pieces.

Comment: If you are allowed to use high level APIs, for each piece, create an image an use Sikuli to find the similar patterns in your board. It is may be not very clear in my post, but Sikuli is an OCR and Pattern Matcher program.

Comment: Ah, thanks :) I do not have any code in place yet, i have the plans for the code, the workflows etc.

Comment: Okay. In that case, you can examine the individual pixels of the image. The docs contain lots of examples how to do that.